# can't access express sub routes on with ngnix proxy pass

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I'm deploying a MERN stack app on to ec2 and I have rann in to issues with sub routes not being accessible.

server.js

```
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors()); 


app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
res.status(400).send({httpStatus:400, response: "Invalid Request. Only valid json requests accepted."})
});

app.get('/api',(req,res) => res.send("hello world"))
app.post('/api/users/create',(req,res) => console.log("creating user..."))
app.listen(5000,'localhost',() => console.log('listening on 5000'))
```

nginx config file:

```
server {
listen 80;
 #server_name your_domain.com;
  location / {
      # This would be the directory where your React app's static files are stored at
       root /my-app/client/build/;
       try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
  location /api/ {

   proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

 }
```

}

The static files and single routes work but routes with subroute don't work..request times out. any help?

Answer (score 0):

You're never ending the request, that's why it times out.

```
app.post('/api/users/create',(req,res) => {
  console.log("creating user...");
  res.send('created');
})
```